# how is this yang notification valid?

Tags: ietf-netmod-yang

yang 1.1 spec has this example,
The following example defines a notification in a data node:

```
 module example-interface-module {
   yang-version 1.1;
   namespace "urn:example:interface-module";
   prefix "if";

   container interfaces {
     list interface {
       key "name";
       leaf name {
         type string;
       }
       notification interface-enabled {
         leaf by-user {
           type string;
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

A corresponding XML instance example of the complete notification:

```
 <notification
   xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:notification:1.0">
   <eventTime>2008-07-08T00:01:00Z</eventTime>
   <interfaces xmlns="urn:example:interface-module">
     <interface>
       <name>eth1</name>
       <interface-enabled>
         <by-user>fred</by-user>
       </interface-enabled>
     </interface>
   </interfaces>
 </notification>
```

My question is, when I raise a notification from server, I thought the notification content would be this :

```
<notification
   xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:notification:1.0">
   <eventTime>2008-07-08T00:01:00Z</eventTime>
   <interface-enabled xmlns="urn:example:interface-module">
      <by-user>fred</by-user>
   </interface-enabled>
 </notification>
```

But, such a notification will be useless without identifying the data node for which the notification is relevant.

I guess my question is, what rule/text in the spec tells me how to form the payload correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7950#section-7.16.2

> When a notification node is defined as a child to a data node, the
>  element defined in [RFC5277] contains a hierarchy of
> nodes that identifies the node in the datastore. **It MUST contain all
> containers and list nodes from the top level down to the list or
> container containing the notification**.

The notification payload must include all ancestor container/lists up to the module root. Only then it is always possible to identify the exact node to which the notification is referring.